# Plant health tile layer

Tags: dronedeploy

Hi i've displayed my dronedeploy map with leaflet.js.

Is it possible to add dronedeploy's Plant Health (NDVI) layer to that map?

Also i was able to add ndvi layer using  https://tiles_2_prod.dronedeploy.com/unsafe/smart/filters:vegetation_index(NDVI,0.2,0.5,NGB):cmap(RdYlGn)/ 
as a prefix.

Problem is i've hardcoded 0.2 and 0.5 as thresholds and i would like to use dronedeploy's calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no supported way to achieve this. 
Also please note the tile urls will be undergoing some changes in the future so hacking them to suit your needs may provide unexpected behavior.
It also would most likely result in any app submission either not getting approved or needing extra review.

We are looking into the future of our api, and exposing these variables.

- I am a DroneDeploy Engineer on the Platform Team.